# how to switch CPL3 to CPL0

Tags: assembly, x86, interrupt, osdev

I write a bootloader which i want to switch to ring0 from ring3 by sofaware interrupt.
but it don't work.

```
org 0x7c00


mov dx,0x92
in al,dx
or al,2
out dx,al

mov eax,cr0
or eax,1
mov cr0,eax


lgdt [gdt_pointer]
mov ax,0x10
mov ds,ax
mov ss,ax
jmp 0x8:flush


[bits 32]
flush:

lidt [idt_pointer]


push (4<<3) | (3)  ;;SS 
push 0xffff        ;;ESP
push 0             ;;EFLAGS
push (3<<3) | (3)  ;;CS 
push ring3         ;;EIP
iret
jmp $

ring3:
mov ax,4<<3        ;;DS 
mov ds,ax

int 0
jmp $

idt_function:
    ;!!!!
    ;!!!! question:   why CPL keep 3 ????? 
    ;!!!! shouldn't dpl = 0?
    ;!!!! what should i do to switch to ring0???????
    ;!!!!

nop
jmp $


;;=================data==================
;;GDT
gdt_pointer:
dw 39
dd gdt_arrays

gdt_arrays:
dq 0
dq 0xCF9E000000FFFF ;DPL=0
dq 0xCF92000000FFFF ;DPL=0
dq 0xCFFE000000FFFF ;DPL=3
dq 0xCFF2000000FFFF ;DPL=3

;;IDT
idt_pointer:
dw 7
dd idt_arrays

idt_arrays:
;
dw idt_function
dw 1<<3 ;;
db 0
db 0xee ;;DPL=3，
dw 0


times 510-($-$$) db 0
db 0x55
db 0xaa
;;=================data==================
```

Doesn't the application(RING3) go to a higher privilege code space（RING0) via system interrupt, why do I still keep CPL=3 here?
If the privilege is not enhanced (CPL=3), how can I use the stunt instructions (CPL=0), such as hlt, lgdt, etc.?

Comment: You set up `mov ds,ax` *after* `lgdt [gdt_pointer]`, and you do it with `mov ax,0x10` which doesn't match your `org` setting.  Unless you get lucky with whatever the BIOS leaves in DS, you might not be loading GDTR with the right stuff.  **Single-step your code in Bochs with its built-in debugger to see what's happening.**

Comment: actually, it can work... i push these code on https://github.com/golangboy/problem     ....my quesition is why it still keep DPL=3 after  Interrupt call ...

Comment: Ok, so you're not using EMU8086.  I removed that tag.

Comment: yes.. maybe i need to remove the tag [emu8086]

Comment: So you specify the conforming flag on your code segment entries in the GDT. If you use `conforming`  then if you are at a CPL>0 and move to a lower CPL the CPL will not change when the transfer is made. This is why your CPL=3 after you did `int 0`.  Set the conforming bit in your Code segment to non-conforming, Change `dq 0xCF9E...` to `dq 0xCF9A...` and `dq 0xCFFE...` to `dq 0xCFFA`. This is just the start o your issues. Now that you will be really transitioning from CPL 3 to CPL 0 on an interrupt you will need to create a TSS and add a TSS table entry to your GDT.

Comment: Then once you have a TSS and a TSS entry in your GDT you will need  use the `LTR` instruction to load the TSS segment selector into the TR register. You do this at ring 0 at some point before entering ring 3.

Comment: If you don't set up a TSS and load the `tr` register before you go from Ring 3 to ring 0 when you do the `int 0` you'll likely end up faulting in a way you didn't expect.

Comment: So if I need to go switch ring3 to ring0, I still need to use TSS?  Using interrupt alone don't work?

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!   I'll try to do what you said

Comment: Yep, you will need a TSS to handle software interrupts from user mode (like `int n`) and to handle external interrupts to properly reach ring 0 if you are in ring 3.

Comment: Although the TSS is used for hardware task switching (which you don't do) the TSS is still important if you are switching from a higher CPL to a lower CPL. The TSS will contain the SS and ESP value of the kernel stack to use when making the transition. That will be the only important values to set if your aren't using an IO bitmap. Everything else can be effectively ignored (filled with 0) when not using hardware task switching.

Comment: By the way you say the problem has been solved!!!!  thank you Petch!!!